# Хранение ресурсов в WPF проекте

Tags: c#, wpf

С недавних пор задаюсь вопросом, в какой ситуации лучше хранить ресурсы проекта просто в папке и обращаться к ним с помощью `Uri`, а в какой ситуации лучше добавлять их в `*.resx` файл и работать с ними через этот файл? Да и вообще, в чем преимущества у `*.resx` перед `Uri`, а в чем недостатки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если следовать "протоколу" то нужно использовать конечно же `*.resx`.

Вот те преимущества который дает `*.resx`:
**1)** Файлы ресурсов предоставляют вам простой способ локализовать / интернационализировать ваши приложения .net, автоматически определяя, какой языковой файл resx использовать на основе.
**2)** Изменение ресурсов в производственном приложении без необходимости перекомпилировать все.
**3)** Файлы ресурсов предоставляют вам центральное место для хранения ваших строк, файлов и сценариев и ссылаются на них строго типизированным образом (поэтому компиляция будет нарушена, если вы ссылаетесь на них неправильно).

Comment: То есть `Uri` - это просто вариант "на пролом", если не хочешь заморачиваться?

Comment: можно и так сказать.resx файлы компилируется и добавляется внутри сборки.по этому говорят что сборки состоит из :
1)Windows Header
2)CLR Header
3)Manifest
4)IL code
5)Metadata
6) and Resources

Comment: Простой способ локализовать есть и без resx, через satellite assembly. Ну и для WPF специфические WPF-ресурсы лучше хранить в `ResourceDictionary`, который тоже «просто включается» в проект. Ну и под WPF нету простого способа загрузить обыкновенную картинку из ResX или Embedded Resource, только из обыкновенного Resource.